# How to run Visual Studio C# Interactive scripts in windows?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, read-eval-print-loop

How do you run the C# Interactive thing in Visual Studio as a stand-alone script host in windows?

It seems a bit of a waste to only have the amazing possibilities of C# Script inside VS, it should be made part of windows so we can run .c# scripts everywhere and all the time and not have to deal with the strangeness, obscurity and unintuitiveness of an undocumented PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

There's the `scriptcs` project, which does exactly that. Check out [scriptcs.net](http://scriptcs.net/).

Comment: That, also a good editor that can be extended with intellisense and auto run => atom + omnisharp-atom package + atom-runner package

Answer (score 1):

On .NET Core you can install the 'scripts' tool and run stored C# scripts:
https://github.com/filipw/dotnet-script

or run in REPL mode:
https://github.com/filipw/dotnet-script#repl

Comment: and what's the difference? pro and cons of the two?

Comment: it's the same tool. you can either run a script saved as a csx file or in REPL mode you can run commands interactively. check out the link for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can run run csi.exe from "Developer Command Prompt for VS2015" or directly from its location on disk (for me `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\csi.exe`).